# Stat Mech: Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution of Momenta

Tags: physical-chemistry, statistical-mechanics

I'm trying to show that the MB distribution of scalar momentum that I've found is properly normalized but I'm stuck. My process: I started with the MB distribution of momentum in 2D and found the normalization factor. Then I'm asked to find the distribution for scalar momentum (where only the magnitude of momentum matters) and prove that it's properly normalized. I transformed from Cartesian to polar coordinates and used a 2D Jacobian matrix. The thing is, once I try to prove it's normalized, I get stuck with an expression that goes to zero and I can't find where I went wrong. I'd appreciate any input. Thanks!

MB dust of momentum in 2D, normalized:
$$ f(\textbf{p}) = \frac{\beta}{2\pi m} e^{\frac{-\beta \textbf{p}^2}{2 m}} $$

To find $F(p)$, we integrate over the polar angle and integrate out the angle-dependence.

From Cartesian to polar coordinates:
$$ dp_x dp_y  = det(J)* dp d\theta = p*dp d\theta$$

The probability of finding p between p and p+dp:
$$prob(p,p+dp) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\textbf{p}) p*dp d\theta = 2\pi p \frac{\beta}{2\pi m} e^{\frac{-\beta p^2}{2 m}} dp = p \frac{\beta}{m} e^{\frac{-\beta p^2}{2 m}} dp$$
Therefore,

$$ F(p) = p \frac{\beta}{m} e^{\frac{-\beta p^2}{2 m}}$$

Then to prove F(p) is properly normalized,

$$ 1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p \frac{\beta}{m} e^{\frac{-\beta p^2}{2 m}} dp $$
$$ = \frac{\beta}{m} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p e^{\frac{-\beta p^2}{2 m}} dp $$

but by symmetry,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p e^{\frac{-\beta \textbf{p}^2}{2 m}} dp = 0$$

Comment: I can't see where the error is exactly, but it has to be in your conversion to polar coordinates. In Cartesian, the integral is clear if you note that $p^2=p_x^2+p_y^2$ and then evaluate each part of the double integral using the formula for the standard Gaussian integral.

Comment: I've actually spotted it now. In your conversion to polar coordinates, you did not account for the change in the limits of integration. Magnitude of p can only go from zero to infinity, and if you make this change you will get the same result as doing it with Cartesian.

Comment: Yes, I see that the bounds of integrations was where I went wrong. Thanks for the help!